# Select event using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to disable a text box when selected a certain value.

example

```
<select name="license" id="license">

<option value="1">Free</option>
<option value="2">Commercial</option>

</select>
```

When selected free i want the text box id price to be disable.

```
<input type="text" class="input" id="price" name="price" value=""/>
```

How can i do this using jQuery. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){
  $("#license").change(function(){
     $("#price").prop("disabled",$(this).val() === "1");
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j8sZf/

Answer (score 1):

You can bind `change` event with the option and use `val()` to get the selected value to condition on it.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/J8zzr/)**

```
$('#license').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "2") 
         $('#price').prop('disabled', true);
    else 
         $('#price').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made a jsfiddle for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/DMMFv/

> $(document).ready(function(){
>
> $("#license").change(function(){
>
> ```
> if($(this).val()=="1"){
>     $(".input").attr("disabled","disabled");
> } else {
>     $(".input").removeAttr('disabled');
> }
>  });
> ```
>
> });

Comment: It appears that from 1.6 the prop method is more suited.  I will leave my answer as previously written as it may be easier for some people to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code

```
$(function(){
 $("#license").change(function(){
   if(parseInt($(this).val()) === 1){
        $("#price")attr("enabled");}
    else
    { 
    $("#price").removeAttr("enabled");
}
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
$(function(){

  //Catch when dropdown menu item was changed
  $('#license').on('change',function(){

  //Get selected item
  var selectedItem = $('#license').find(':selected').text();

  //Check what was selected
  if(selectedItem == "Free")
  {
    $('#price').attr('disabled',true);    
  } 
  else
    {
      $('#price').removeAttr('disabled');
    }

   });

  //Trigger change event so the check happens on page load as well as when list item is changed
  $('#license').change();

});
```

Complete working JSBin:
http://jsbin.com/uwevir/1/